# Compiz "screen edge bindings actions" like but without Compiz

Tags: command-line, scripts, screen

I wish to use a tool to run `command` (or `script`) when the mouse hits the edge of screen, but without Compiz. What's tool is like of "edges actions" Compiz ? Compiz is not supported on my laptop, so I'm searching for another solution.

I wish to execute commands when hit edge of screen associated with mouse + buttons, like the Compiz function but without Compiz. I tried Brightside but it doesn't support edge to run commands, only corners.

- [Link : Compiz screen edge](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM#Screen_Edges)
- [Link : Brightside for Linux](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/set-up-hot-corners-edge-flipping-in.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xinput --query-state $XID` or `xdotool getmouselocation` to get the mouse position. The badass feature of `xdotool getmouselocation` is its `--shell` option, with that and `eval` you can assign the values to variables without the need to cut any output in pieces, for example:

```
$ eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
$ echo $X, $Y
604, 778
```

With that we can build a `while` loop that constantly tests for the desired value, e.g.:

```
while :;
do
  eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
  (( $X <= 20 )) && break
  sleep .1
done
```

This will run until `$X` is 20 or less and test every 100 milliseconds. I recommend to build a script for your exact situation out of that, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

id=9 # device XID, run xinput without any option to get a list of devices and their IDs
interval=.01 # sleep interval between tests in seconds

# edge areas
# to display the current mouse coordinates run xdotool getmouselocation
# syntax: x_min x_max y_min y_max
e1=(200 1079 0 20)
e2=(1259 1279 200 823)
e3=(200 1079 1003 1023)
e4=(0 20 200 823)

while :; do
  eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
  if ( [ ${#e1[@]} -ne 0 ] && (( $X >= ${e1[0]} && $X <= ${e1[1]} && $Y >= ${e1[2]} && $Y <= ${e1[3]} )) ); then
    # your commands for edge area e1
    echo "Your mouse was detected inside the monitored area no. 1 at $X, $Y."
    sleep 2
  fi
  if ( [ ${#e2[@]} -ne 0 ] && (( $X >= ${e2[0]} && $X <= ${e2[1]} && $Y >= ${e2[2]} && $Y <= ${e2[3]} )) ); then
    # your commands for edge area e2
    echo "Your mouse was detected inside the monitored area no. 2 at $X, $Y."
    sleep 2
  fi
  if ( [ ${#e3[@]} -ne 0 ] && (( $X >= ${e3[0]} && $X <= ${e3[1]} && $Y >= ${e3[2]} && $Y <= ${e3[3]} )) ); then
    # your commands for edge area e3
    echo "Your mouse was detected inside the monitored area no. 3 at $X, $Y."
    sleep 2
  fi
  if ( [ ${#e4[@]} -ne 0 ] && (( $X >= ${e4[0]} && $X <= ${e4[1]} && $Y >= ${e4[2]} && $Y <= ${e4[3]} )) ); then
    # your commands for edge area e4
    echo "Your mouse was detected inside the monitored area no. 4 at $X, $Y."
    sleep 2
  fi
  sleep $interval
done
```

I created some edge areas as examples, those start and end 200px from the corners and cover the area within 20px from the edge for my 1279x1023px screen – you'll need to adjust them to your needs. If you need less areas just delete or comment the others. The commands you want to execute go in the `if` clauses inside the while function. To prevent multiple calls when you leave the mouse inside the edge area you may use `sleep`, `break` or just test whether the command in question already runs.

Comment: From this commands, I made a `script` to close active window when right click on right edge and open Firefox when right click on top edge: [here](https://github.com/Philippe734/Snippets/blob/master/Edges.actions/Edges.actions.sh)